# Completely new Time Machine backup?

Tags: time-machine

I made use of Time Machine to restore my Mac's OS and data to a new drive after the old one failed. Time Machine doesn't seem to recognize that the new drive and the back ups are related. Is there a method to connect the two, or do I need to wipe that drive containing the old history, and just start a new TM backup?

Answer (score 2):

The Time Machine backups became disassociated with the new drive because of the change to the UUID of the new drive. With a little usage of `tmutil` in Terminal following the [directions here](http://pondini.org/TM/B6.html), you can rebuild the association of the Time Machine backups to the new drive.

Comment: I appreciate the response. That terminal command isn't available in 10.6.8. Strange enough.

Comment: Ahh, yes, pre-Lion there is no `tmutil`. You may have to do some Googling to find the answer on how to achieve this, which the author of the linked article describes as "very techie".